What is the reason for the difference between Eloi and Eli?

Mark 15:34, And at the ninth hour Jesus cried out with a loud voice,
saying, “Eloi, Eloi, lama sabachthani?” which is translated, “My God, My God, why have You forsaken Me?”
Matthew 27:46, And about the ninth hour Jesus cried out with a
loud voice, saying, “Eli, Eli, lama sabachthani?” that is, “My God,
My God, why have You forsaken Me?”

What is the difference? Why is there a difference between Eloi and Eli? What was actually said? Which should we say to be accurate?

Mark's book focuses on the Messenger of the Covenant (see Mark 1:1,2 and Malachi 3: 1-4) whilst Matthew is writing in regard to the kingdom of the heavens (literal) against the background of the Jewish state and government.
Thus Mark cites the actual dialect that Jesus of Nazareth spoke in his anguish. It is the actual speech of the Messenger of the Covenant, the  dialect, sometimes called Aramaic, almost certainly a dialect formed during the captivity in Babylon, bearing similarities to Chaldee.
Whilst Matthew cites the Hebrew text that Jesus was quoting, the pure Hebrew of scripture.

Both of these are usually understood to be Aramaic renditions of Psalm 22:1. But Matthew's version is closer to the Hebrew, changing "my God" from Eloi to Eli. The reason for this change probably has to do with Matthew's context (see footnote here), where Jesus' statement is misunderstood by onlookers to be a reference to Elijah.

47 Some of the bystanders who heard it said, “This one is calling for
Elijah.” 48 Immediately one of them ran to get a sponge; he soaked it
in wine, and putting it on a reed, gave it to him to drink. 49 But the
rest said, “Wait, let us see if Elijah comes to save him.”

In the language of the time "el-ee" (my God) and "el-ee-a-hu" (Elijah) would be much easier to confuse than "el-oi" and "el-ee-a-hu". As to which is a more accurate version of what Jesus actually said, this is complicated. For one thing, it depends on whether he actually quoting Ps. 22 or simply saying in Aramaic, "my God, my God why have your forsaken me." It also depends on whether he might have mixed the Hebrew and Aramaic - not at all implausible - if he recited the Psalm. Finally, it may also be the case that Matthew recorded "Eli" because that is what was reported by an eyewitness, even though it was really Eloi.

There is only a difference in the two gospel accounts in some translations when reporting these particular words of Jesus from the cross. To grasp this, the difference between what onlookers unaware of what was really happening thought and expected, needs to be contrasted with the two apostles' reports, written some years after the resurrection of Christ.
The crowd of mainly Jewish people looking on was comprised of those who had never accepted the testimony of Jesus as to who he was. They were still thinking in terms of a future Messiah. They never saw Jesus as such. From their grasp of Hebrew prophecies, they associated Messiah coming with another messenger, Elijah. Here is an explanation from the NIV which has Jesus saying 'Eloi, Eloi', despite the Nestle Greek text having 'Eli' twice. The verses following report the crowd saying he was calling for Elijah, and waiting to see if the bone-dead Elijah actually appeared.

"27:46  Eloi, Eloi, lama sabachthani? A mixture of Aramaic and
Hebrew, translated by Matthew for his readers (see note on Mk 15:34).
NIV Study Bible, p.1457, 1987 Ed.

Matthew was writing for a mainly Jewish readership, but (writing his gospel account in Greek), those Jewish readers also knew Greek. Here is the comment on Mark's account:

"15:35  The words were spoken in Aramaic (but with some Hebrew
characteristics), one of the languages commonly spoken in Jesus' day.
They reveal how deeply Jesus felt his abandonment by God as he bore
the sins of mankind (but see note on Psalm 22:1). (Ibid. p. 1499)

The note on Psalm 22 reads:

"... No other psalm fitted quite so aptly the circumstances of Jesus
at his crucifixion. Hence on the cross he took it to his lips, and the
Gospel writers, especially Matthew and John, frequently alluded to it
in their accounts of Christ's passion... [seeing] in the passion of
Jesus the fulfilment of this cry of the righteous sufferer. The author
of Hebrews placed the words of v. 22 on Jesus' lips (2:12). No psalm
is quoted more frequently in the NT." (Ibid. p. 788)

Putting those three notes together, it may be seen that the Christians who personally knew Jesus were clear in their understanding that he was applying Psalm 22:1 to himself, so they did likewise. This gives the case for Jesus crying out to God and not to Elijah.
Yet something needs to be said about the Jewish on-lookers who did not have faith in Jesus, and from the same source, a comment on Mark 15:35:

"Elijah.  The bystanders mistook the first words of Jesus' cry
("Eloi, Eloi") to be a cry for Elijah. It was commonly believed that
Elijah would come in times of critical need to protect the innocent
and rescue the righteous (v. 36)." (Ibid. p. 1499)

Yet the last word on the matter I would give to a modern author in his book on Mark. He addresses the profound mystery of events on the cross (which even the disciples did not have revealed to them until after Christ's resurrection):

"The world's religion was ignorant of it. And of this blind obscurity,
the three hours darkness  bore mute testimony. And at the ninth hour
(three in the afternoon) Jesus cried with a loud voice, Eloi Eloi, lama sabachthani? which is, being interpreted, My God my God, why hast
thou forsaken me? Why had God forsaken him? He was forsaken because of
the sins of his people, removed from them and borne by Jesus in his
own body on the tree. He was cut off because God had made him to be
sin for us, that it might be condemned in his flesh on our behalf.
The wrath of God then having fallen out of eternity upon the
sin-bearer on the cross, God having being glorified in righteousness
by the judgment of sins in the Substitute, what remained? The blind
ignorance and superstition of man remained, so foolish as to suppose
Jesus would call upon the saints, confounding 'Eloi' with 'Elias'."
Mark, John Metcalfe, p. 212, 2009 reprint, emphasis mine. http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

Therein lies the difference between religious, but unbelieving Jews, their superstitious expectations and lack of faith in Christ causing them to mishear 'Elijah', while the disciples writing after Christ's foretold death and resurrection correctly repeated the words of Psalm 22:1 as being on his parched lips. There was the difference, and what was actually said. Matthew 27:46, NIV, gives the correct words as "My God, my God" as does Mark.

+1. We’ll quoted answer.

Language DifferencesAny confusion in English translations is cleared up by noting that two different, but related languages are in play in old Judaea. Matthew uses Hebrew in repeating Jesus's quotation from Psalm 22:1, Eli. This is why many thought Jesus referring to the famous Hebrew prophet of old, Elijah. (Matthew 27:45) Recall that the audience of Matthew's Gospel were mainly Jews who were familiar with Hebrew linguistically.
However, Mark tells tells this story using the Aramaic wording, eloi. It is the Aramaic word for "God" with the possessive ending, "my": "my God, my God" (Mark 15:35)
The rest of the phrase, lama sabachthani, is in Aramaic.
Accuracy of the usage of these words, is not the issue, in repeating this  narration of the Crucifixion. Just preference of language (Aramaic or Hebrew) is allowed here.
CommentaryWhile some readers see angst and desperation in these words; commentators note an affirmation of faith. Jesus was aware of the fact that Psalm 22 ends with a final consciousness of victory! (See also John 16:32, God is always with me.) For verbiage about rejection, there were plenty of words in Lamentations  to draw from. But God was still "His God" on the cross.
ReferencesLenski, INTERPRETATION OF MARK'S GOSPEL; PULPIT COMMENTARY, in loc.; R. Alan Cole, TYNDALE N.T. COMMENTARY.

+1 Good answer and well referenced.
